# Winamp Plugin - Can I detect a redirect in minibrowser?

Tags: c++, winapi, winamp

I am developing a Winamp plugin that requires a user a to authenticate on a website that I display in the minibrowser. After the user authenticates I would then like control to be given back to my plugin.

My question is: is there a way to detect when the user has been redirected in the minibrowser or can I somehow capture events from the minibrowser so that I can determine when the users authentication has been completed?

If someone can point me to the correct header functions needed (from the SDK) or provide me with an example I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!